# How to submit form in new window, then redirect the parent page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I am having some browser compatibility problems with what I am trying to do here.

I have a form on a webpage :

```
 <form method="POST" target="_blank" 
       onsubmit="refreshparent()" action="https://processor.com/payment.php" >
       <input type="HIDDEN" name="unit_key" value="92393d" >
       <input type="HIDDEN" name="cost" value="100.20" >
       <input type="HIDDEN" name="user_id" value="92393d" >
       <input type="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT"  value="Click to open payment site" >
 </form>
```

When the user submits the form, I want a new window to open and I want a javascript function called "refreshparent" to get called.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       function refreshparent()
       {
           alert("test");
           window.location.replace ("http://mysite.com/main-menu.html");
        }
  </script>
```

This works in some browsers, but not in Chrome.  Is there a better way to get a form submit and javascript call to happen from the same button click ?

Comment: What does not work in Chrome? The blank tab, the redirection?

Comment: The form submit button successfully opens in a new window/tab in all browsers.  But in Chrome, the page doesn't redirect to http://mysite.com/main-menu.html.

Comment: Yes, I get the alert but no redirect.  I wondered if the focus has moved to the new window after pressing the submit button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `target='_blank'` to open the new window you could just prevent the default submit action and use `window.open` instead.  Not sure, but that might solve your Chrome issue.